# How to join with / subselect in a system-period temporal table

Tags: sql, db2, temporal-database

I have a db2 database and a system-period temporal table, so it's easy to get the data that was valid on a specific date by

```
SELECT mtt_sometimes_updated_value FROM my_temp_table FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP('2018-01-31') WHERE mtt_key = '...'
```

This will give me one row (as I filter by key), but I also could add `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` in case I wouldn't have the key in the where condition.

Now I want to use this as a subselect or join with `another_table` which has the value of `mtt_key` in column `at_key` and an `at_additional_key`, and an `at_date_column`. What I want is to combine with the `my_temp_table` to get every row in `another_table` enhanced by the `mtt_sometimes_updated_value`.

When I try what seems to be intuitive

```
SELECT at_key, at_additional_key, at_date_column,
  (SELECT mtt_sometimes_updated_value 
   FROM my_temp_table FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF at_date_column 
   WHERE mtt_key = at_key)
FROM another_table
```

I get an error `INVALID PERIOD SPECIFICATION OR PERIOD CLAUSE FOR PERIOD SYSTEM_TIME. REASON CODE = 03. SQLCODE=-20524` - I can find the the error description on https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n20524.html - but I don't really understand it - it seems that it's not possible to use a column of another table `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF`.

So, can I join somehow with these temporal tables or how do I get the wanted info out of those two tables? Any ideas? Any hints? Thanks.

The only way I see is the complicated way to manually try to deal with the timestamps generated by the system-period temporal table, but I hope that there is an easier way somewhere ... or just a misunderstanding of the syntax in my subselect

Here's some sample data to clarify what I have and what I want:

The table `my_temporal_table` has one current row which was updated on 2018-01-07

```
mt_key | mtt_so_up_val | (was updated on)
-------+---------------+-----------------
1      | Z             | (2018-01-07)
```

former updates were on

```
1      | Y             | (2018-01-02)
1      | X             | (2017-12-24)
```

The table `another_table` looks like this

```
at_key | at_additional_key | at_date_column
-------+-------------------+---------------
1      | A                 | 2018-01-01
1      | B                 | 2018-01-02
1      | C                 | 2018-01-03
1      | D                 | 2018-01-04
1      | E                 | 2018-01-05
1      | F                 | 2018-01-06
1      | G                 | 2018-01-07
1      | H                 | 2018-01-08
1      | I                 | 2018-01-09
```

There may be more data for different keys, but if I filter for key = 1 then the result should be

```
at_key | at_additional_key | at_date_column | mtt_so_up_val
-------+-------------------+----------------+--------------
1      | A                 | 2018-01-01     | X
1      | B                 | 2018-01-02     | Y
1      | C                 | 2018-01-03     | Y
1      | D                 | 2018-01-04     | Y
1      | E                 | 2018-01-05     | Y
1      | F                 | 2018-01-06     | Y
1      | G                 | 2018-01-07     | Z
1      | H                 | 2018-01-08     | Z
1      | I                 | 2018-01-09     | Z
```

So I want to enhance the table with the values that were valid on that specific date. Hope that's clear enough ...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sample data added

Answer (score 1):

You are rigth using a column is currently not supported - in this sytax you have to specify the date or timestamp explicitly.
To lift this restriction I have opened a [RFE (Request for Enhancement) - ID 
111742](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=111742)  It is already an uncommitted candidate but vote for it if you support my request.

You could still solve it the traditional way (without the new syntax).
I highly recommend this [blog article "Fun with Date Ranges"](https://www.idug.org/p/bl/et/blogaid=672) for details